# Exposing Q_PROPERTY from private member

Tags: c++, qt, qproperty

In the code I'm working on I need to expose `Q_PROPERTY` from private member(s) through one integrating `QWidget`. Something like this would be nice:

```
class MyWidget: public QWidget{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(QString headerText MEMBER myLabel.text NOTIFY QLabel::notify)

private:
   QLabel myLabel
}
```

Is it possible to do so and how? Or do I have to write all the get/set methods manually?

Comment: At the moment, it's only generally possible by modifying moc. Note though that `QLabel` doesn't have a notifier signal.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write your own getter/setter:

```
QString getText()const{ return myLabel.text();}
void setText( const QString& s){ myLabel.setText(s);}
```

And after you may define a Q_PROPERTY for it:

```
Q_PROPERTY( QString headerText READ getText WRITE setText)
```

Note: for some versions of Qt, you may found some tricks working, but they may stop working in a following version. For this reason, it is probably better to stick to common/standard behavior.

EDITED:

To add a bit of formalism to this answer, here is a related bug:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47695?jql=text%20~%20%22Q_PROPERTY%20member%22

Summarizing: In Qt<=5.4 it was possible to use structure members in the Q_PROPERTY MEMBER parameter. This feature "Worked by chance" and is not supported from now.

Comment: I hoped there is some standard way without having to re-implement all getters and setters.

Comment: There is room for improvement, I agree: for example, I miss also Q_PROPERTY of custom type (struct/class) and Q_PROPERTY accessing members of a struct/class.

Comment: @AdrianMaire You can use `Q_PROPERTY` with custom types. _"Custom types used by properties need to be registered using the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() macro so that their values can be stored in QVariant objects. This makes them suitable for use with both static properties declared using the Q_PROPERTY() macro in class definitions and dynamic properties created at run-time."_

Comment: @BenjaminT: To my knowledge, you may use QVariant, but not a custom struct. Also, QtCreator will not understand your type. If I am wrong, please, provide me an example, it would be very useful.

Comment: @AdrianMaire if you have `struct MyStruct {...};` just add `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyStruct)` and then you can write `Q_PROPERTY(MyStruct myProp READ myProp WRITE setMyProp NOTIFY myPropChanged)`. You might need to add a call to `qRegisterMetaType()` if you do more advanced stuff.

Comment: @BenjaminT: Good to know. thanks. Not very useful still as not understood by QtDesigner.

Comment: @AdrianMaire Qt Designer it not the only use for Qt properties. For instance one could use custom type properties with QML or with qpropertybrowser.

Answer (score 1):

The OP wants to avoid the manual boilerplate of getter/setter pairs that would not need to be written if we didn't want to expose a Q_PROPERTY.

I don't have a solution for that, but I am still interested in the "private members" aspect of the question.

In my case, I arrived here because I wanted to hide these required setters from all other code *EXCEPT* for Qt binding code.

Empirically, using Qt 5.12, the following does work for me:

```
   class HolderOfSomeInteger : public QObject {
     Q_OBJECT

     Q_PROPERTY(int someInt
                READ GetInt
                NOTIFY someIntChanged)

    signals:
     void someIntChanged();

    private:  // <--- private section
     // My own other classes cannot access this, but 
     // the QML binding works as expected anyhow.
     int GetInt() const { return some_integer; }

     int some_integer = 0;
   };
```

So, in addition to keeping the `int` data-member `some_integer` private, I apparently can simply put the `GetInt()` getter in the `private` section as well.

However, as @adrian-maire said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42348046/10278, "for some versions of Qt, you may find some tricks working, but they may stop working in a following version."

As [this Qt Property System documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190620213343/https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) looks today, it only says

> "A READ accessor function is required if no MEMBER variable was
>   specified. It is for reading the property value. Ideally, a const
>   function is used for this purpose, and it must return either the
>   property's type or a const reference to that type."

It says nothing about whether the accessor function must be public or private.

---

I dug some more, and I think I found out why the property binding still works with a private getter.

The `Q_OBJECT` macro declares that your class has methods `qt_metacall` and `qt_static_metacall`.  Qt's `MOC` then generates the bodies of these methods.

The property binding is accomplished using those methods. Since those methods are members of your class, they (of course) can call even the `private` member functions that your class provides.